# unable to open tcp connection with host 'localhost:1433' in azure container app

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances, azure-container-apps

Hello am new to Azure platform. I have created a hello world basic azure container app which is running fine and am able to access the app over internet. I added database connection to connect and execute some SQL queries. I understand it's trying to establish connection through TCP and fails to do so. I have added principal id to SQL database IAM too. Application is running inside same subscription as SQL Server db.

Two days ago I created a container instance and run the same image and was able to connect to db. Issue started when I created container apps and started using containers inside. So am sure this is a problem how I set up and managing access to container apps.

2023-10-13T04:11:08.584085724Z INFO: 2023/10/13 04:11:08 *****Server strting****
2023-10-13T04:11:09.818464540Z server has started
2023-10-13T04:14:29.970589453Z INFO: 2023/10/13 04:14:29 Root request

2023-10-13T04:17:55.852719129Z INFO: 2023/10/13 04:17:55 DB process creation started

**2023-10-13T04:17:55.853183078Z 2023/10/13 04:17:55 unable to open tcp connection with host 'localhost:1433': dial tcp [::1]:1433: connect: connection refused**

Comment: Where is your DB Running? Is it a different container, azure SQL? You are trying to connect to localhost which means you are trying to access dB from within the network namespace.

Comment: Ok, why does it takes localhost? I read connection string from azure keyvault. Connection string is tcp:

connString := secrets.KeysProvider.GetSecret(constants.MyDBContext)

My db running at: myappname-sql-dev.database.windows.net

Comment: Can you check your connectivity to KV ? looks like it is not resolving properly

Comment: hmm I see this logs.. I added Object Id in keyvault but still I see this errors

2023-10-14T13:55:30.945489654Z INFO: 2023/10/14 13:55:30 Get secret failed :: DefaultAzureCredential: failed to acquire a token.
2023-10-14T13:55:30.94 Attempted credentials:
2023-10-14T13:55:30.94  EnvironmentCredential: missing environment variable AZURE_TENANT_ID
2023-10-14T13:55:WorkloadIdentityCredential: no client ID specified. Check pod configuration or set ClientID in the options
ManagedIdentityCredential: managed identity timed out
AzureCLICredential: Azure CLI not found on path